# Could not build the application for the simulator Flutter IOS

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build

I have this problem when i update my mac os to Big Sur and Xcode. My flutter V is 1.22.5. application is working fine in android this problem in IOS side. I search over the internet and i try all solution but still not working.

i tried removing Pods, Podfile.lock and Podfile and i do't get any result.

Anyone have an idea about this issue ?

[image]

Comment: did you try https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/75113 ?

Comment: we need to add ffi: ^1.0.0

Comment: i don't use ffi -- should i add it ?

Comment: Yes, give it a try

Comment: i tried it and i got same error !!